# Determining a Local File's Mime Type (Content-type) With PHP

Tags: php, file, content-type, mime-types

I am trying to determine a file's mime type.  I've tried a few methods, but haven't come up with anything that gives consistent output.  I've tried `$mime = mime_content_type($file)` and `$mime = exec('file -bi ' . $file)`.  I am serving up images, CSS, and JavaScript.

Example `mime_content_type()` output:

- jquery.min.js - text/plain
- editor.js - text/plain
- admin.css - text/plain
- controls.css - application/x-troff
- logo.png - text/plain

Example `exec(...)` output:

- jquery.min.js - text/plain; charset=us-ascii
- editor.js - text/x-c++; charset=us-ascii
- admin.css - text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
- controls.css - text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
- logo.png - image/png

As can be seen here, the results are all over the place.

**My PHP version is 5.2.6**

---

**SOLUTION** (thanks to Jacob)

```
$mimetypes = array(
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpg',
    'css' => 'text/css',
    'js' => 'text/javascript',
);
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
if (array_key_exists($path_parts['extension'], $mimetypes)) {
    $mime = $mimetypes[$path_parts['extension']];
} else {
    $mime = 'application/octet-stream';
}
```

Comment: You said that you were using 5.2.6, how then are you using `fileinfo`?

Comment: `pathinfo()` has been around since PHP 4.0.3 - http://us.php.net/pathinfo

Comment: upvoted for adding solution, that said, the solution provided is inherently insecure as it only checks  file extensions and should not be used on uploaded files to check validity.

Comment: @buggedcom - I agree. In my case, the files are managed by us, so this solution is acceptable. I couldn't find a secure solution that worked. I'd be willing to award an accepted answer for a secure solution that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The [`Fileinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension will do the job, if you're on >= 5.30**

- You should try to avoid having to execute commands
- `mime_content_type` is deprecated in PHP 5.30

---

If unfortunately you are on < 5.30, then I would probably just write it myself, it's a lot more reliable than what you're getting from the above functions/commands.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$filename = 'FILENAME HERE';
$mimetypes = array('png' => 'image/png', 'jpg' => 'image/jpg', 'css' => 'text/css',
    'js' => 'application/x-javascript'
    // any other extensions that you may be serving      
);

$ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1, strlen($filename)));
if(array_key_exists($ext, $mimetypes)) {
    $mime = $mimetypes[$ext];
} else {
    echo 'mime type not found';
}

?>
```

Comment: The Fileinfo is PHP >= 5.3.0. I am on 5.2.6.  I just updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Using your solution, but you should change `in_array()` to `array_key_exists()` and reverse the arguments.